# Connecting multiple AXI4-Lite slaves

Tags: amba

When connecting several AXI4-Lite slaves, must I use some kind of interconnect? If it is guaranteed that each slave decodes a distinct set of addresses, is it possible that the slaves would set their data outputs to high-z and be connected together?

Comment: Actually there is such interconnect, it is created by Vivado itself

Comment: Can you add a link please? If I'm using Vivado, how should I make Vivado add it?

Comment: Create project->create block design->add zynq->add AXI slave->run connection automation (blue link on top of block design)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, can I use the interconnect IP with plain verilog files? (without creating a block design?)

Comment: I have no idea. I think, by this time you are more experienced than me :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are implementations of AXI4-Lite slaves that always provide a valid output even when the address is not in their range. This makes such a bus configuration impossible. I guess using a crossbar is a must.